# resynchronize branch and trunk after undoing revisions in trunk that is needed in branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, versioning

So here's what happened

My trunk contains revision 100 - I do not want revision 100 in trunk - I want it in a branch
so I did svn copy and created a branch for revision 100 (call it Branch-100)

Next I removed changes from revision 100 from trunk via tortoise svn and then committed it into trunk so now trunk doesn't have revision 100 but Branch-100 has it

My question is, now whenever I run `svn merge http://url-to-trunk` from Branch-100, it'll ask to also remove the revision 100 changes in Branch-100 (since those revision 100 changes were removed from trunk)

Is there a way to tell svn that I do indeed want those revisions in Branch-100 so that I can merge from trunk accordingly without deleting revision 100 in Branch-100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
svn merge -c REV --record-only http://url-to-trunk
```

where REV is revision which you want to merge without actually merging the changes.

See also [SVN Book -- Blocking changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.blockchanges)